# pop up user control not rendering correctly when created

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, drawing

I have a class which handles a sort of user control popup, which works by inheriting from System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown. This has worked for the popup type i had currently, of which i shall detail below;

First, is the class which i use to hold the user control in a popup type style;

```
 public class PopupWindow : System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown
{
    private System.Windows.Forms.Control _content;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripControlHost _host;

    public PopupWindow(System.Windows.Forms.Control content)
    {
        //Basic setup...
        this.AutoSize = false;
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
        this.ResizeRedraw = true;
        this.BackColor = content.BackColor;

        this._content = content;
        this._host = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripControlHost(content);

        //Positioning and Sizing
        this.MinimumSize = content.MinimumSize;
        this.MaximumSize = content.Size;
        this.Size = content.Size;
        content.Location = Point.Empty;

        //Add the host to the list
        this.Items.Add(this._host);
    }
}
```

as we can see here, i'm simply passing a control to it, and letting it do the work. When using this on an "onclick" popup, like so, it works fine;

```
 public void Popup(object sender, MouseEventArgs e, other params)
    {

        DevicePopup popupDevice = new DevicePopup();

          //do stuff to the control here before displaying

        PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(popupDevice);
        popup.Show(Cursor.Position);

    }
```

and calling it like so;

```
  this.Controls[btnAdd.Name].MouseClick += (sender, e) =>
            {
                int index = temp;
                generatePopup.Popup(sender, e, mDevices[index], this);
            };
```

doing this successfully creates the popup user control at my mouse click, as intended.

However, i'm now trying to use a second type of popup which spawns when something happens. Below is my new popup class, and calling it;

```
public void AlarmNotificationPopup(IDeviceInterface device)
     {


         try
         {
             AlarmNotification ANotification = new AlarmNotification();

       //do stuff to the control again before displaying


             PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(ANotification);
             popup.Show(100, 100);


         }
         catch (Exception e)
         {
             MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
         }


     }


    AlarmNotificationPopup(device);
```

However, this popup doesn't render / create properly, and looks like so;

[image: Rendering issue]

I'm not entirely sure how to fix this. anyone have any ideas?

Comment: look into the padding and margin of the controls. Are they correct?

Comment: looks the same as far as i can tell.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to try:

I don't think you need your "Basic Setup", so comment that out.  Also, try setting your margins and paddings:

```
public PopupWindow(Control content) {
  // Basic setup...
  // this.AutoSize = false;
  // this.DoubleBuffered = true;
  // this.ResizeRedraw = true;
  // this.BackColor = content.BackColor;

  this._content = content;
  this._host = new ToolStripControlHost(content);
  this._host.Margin = new Padding(0);
  this._host.Padding = new Padding(0);
  this.Padding = new Padding(0);
  this.Margin = new Padding(0);

  //Positioning and Sizing
  this.MinimumSize = content.MinimumSize;
  this.MaximumSize = content.Size;
  this.Size = content.Size;
  content.Location = Point.Empty;

  //Add the host to the list
  this.Items.Add(this._host);
}
```

Make sure your `AlarmNotification` has its `MinimumSize` property set.

If that doesn't help solve the problem, then you probably need to document what the `AlarmNotification` class is doing.